# Regex: Exclude alphabets and extract numbers alone

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, regex-lookarounds

I have a dataframe column that contains data similar to this,

```
1015 - 1540
56.56 - 156
34.46Sq. Meter 
36Sq. Meter 
1000Sq. Meter
```

I need to remove the alphabets and make the data in the column look like below.

```
1015 - 1540
56.56 - 156
34.46 
36
1000
```

I tried the below regex pattern, however, it seems to not work properly. Thanks in advance for helping.

```
(\d*\s\-\s\d*)|(\d*[\.]?\d*)(?=\w)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
df['result'] = df['col'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*-\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?)', expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wvwrlS/1). The regex contains a single capturing group (`Series.str.extract` requires at least one capturing group to return a value) that matches

- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a dot and one or more digits
- `(?:` -  start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\s*-\s*` - a hyphen enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`  - one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a dot and one or more digits
- `)?` - end of the group, match 1 or 0 times (i.e. it is optional).

Answer (score 0):

Delete (by replacing with a blank) all unwanted chars, which match this regex:

```
[^\d .-]|(?<! )-(?! )|(?<=\D)[.]|(?<!-) (?!-)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/LFjNF8vnDW7F0f).

Use `re.sub(thisRegex, '', yourStr)`, ie:

```
cleaned = re.sub('[^\d .-]|(?<! )-(?! )|(?<=\D)[.]|(?<!-) (?!-)', '', str)
```

The regex is an OR or these:

- `[^\d .-]` any char not a digit, space, dot or dash
- `(?<! )-(?! )` dash not next to a space
- `(?<=\D)[.]` dot preceded by a non digit
- `(?<!-) (?!-)` space not next to a dash

If this gets heavy use, consider compiling the regex once and reusing it.